# Compile time buffer decoding

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, c++17, compile-time

I have the following class, where I want to decode a binary input to some value at compile time. It works great as implemented with the static function, but I would like the non static function to work at compile time, is that possible somehow? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class BinaryDecoder
{
public:
    BinaryDecoder(const BinaryDecoder&) = delete;
    BinaryDecoder& operator=(const BinaryDecoder&) = delete;

public:
    BinaryDecoder(const std::uint8_t* buffer, size_t size)
      : m_buffer(buffer),
        m_size(size)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool decode(size_t offset, T& decodedValue) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same< std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::uint32_t>::value)
            return decodeBuffer(offset, decodedValue);

        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr T decode(const std::uint8_t* buffer, const size_t size, const size_t offset) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same< std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::uint32_t>::value)
            return decodeBuffer(buffer, size, offset);

        return 0;
    }

private:
    static constexpr std::uint32_t decodeBuffer(
        const std::uint8_t* buffer,
        const size_t size,
        const size_t offset) noexcept
    {
        if (offset + sizeof(std::uint32_t) > size)
            return 0;

        const uint8_t b0 = buffer[offset], b1 = buffer[offset + 1], b2 = buffer[offset + 2], b3 = buffer[offset + 3];
        return (b0 << 0) | (b1 << 8) | (b2 << 16) | (b3 << 24);
    }

    constexpr bool decodeBuffer(
        const size_t offset,
        std::uint32_t& decodedValue) noexcept
    {
        if (offset + sizeof(std::uint32_t) > m_size)
            return false;

        const uint8_t b0 = m_buffer[offset], b1 = m_buffer[offset + 1], b2 = m_buffer[offset + 2], b3 = m_buffer[offset + 3];
        decodedValue = (b0 << 0) | (b1 << 8) | (b2 << 16) | (b3 << 24);
        return true;
    }

private:
    const std::uint8_t* m_buffer;
    const size_t m_size;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::uint8_t input[] = { 0x84, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x00, 0x90 };       
    static_assert(900 == BinaryDecoder::decode<std::uint32_t>(input, sizeof(input), 0), "Decoded value not equal to 900");

    constexpr std::uint8_t input2[] = { 0x84, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x00, 0x90 };
    BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder(input2, sizeof(input2));
    constexpr std::uint32_t value = 900;
    binaryDecoder.decode(0, value);
    // Should not compile since it is not 900.
    static_assert(900 == value, "Decoded value not equal to 900");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As Vittorio Romeo pointed out in the comment this is no bug. My IDE(Visual Studio 2017) marked my `static_assert` with an error when I had the follwing calls in my main function.

```
    constexpr std::uint32_t value = 0;
    binaryDecoder.decode(0, value);
    static_assert(900 == value, "Decoded value not equal to 900");
```

I just assumed that there was something wrong with my code but it was Visual Studio that was to smart for me. It somehow compiled it in the background and marked it as an error. If I changed the value to 900 it all compiles fine.

Edit2: However it does not decode it at compile time which was what I wanted.

Comment: No constexpr constructor ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are correct I have fixed that. Yes I should have a constexpr constructor but I believe the problem is returning the value from my decode function. I guess I cannot have it as a reference like that?

Comment: @Jarod42 No sorry you are correct that solved the issue with the constexpr constructor. If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: As alternative, you may return a `optional<uint32_t>`

Comment: This works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/UJb3HYYs0nksh54d - what's your issue? [MCVE] of intended usage and error please.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You are correct, see my edit at the bottom.